# Подсчитать количество записей и суммировать значения из нескольких связанных таблиц

Tags: mysql

Есть 4 таблицы между собой связанные. главной таблице `sats` хранится пользовательские данные. по полю `sats.id`подсчитать сколько пользователей зарегистрирован и сгруппировать по полью  `sats_id`. `sats_id` связан с таблицей `sum.id`,(`sats.id = sum.id`). `SELECT sum.name AS 'категория', COUNT(sats.sats_id) AS 'пользователи' FROM sats JOIN sum ON sats.sats_id = sum.id GROUP BY sum.name;`. тут нужно еще одно поле суммировать, таблица `dslam.dslamType_id`. сгруппировать так же по полю `sum.name`

[image]

получается такой результат:  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получается вот такой результат `SELECT dslam.sats_id, SUM(dslamtype.name) FROM dslam JOIN dslamtype ON dslam.dslamType_id = dslamtype.id GROUP BY sats_id;`  получается вот такой результат [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

теперь нужно их объединить

ссылка на исходный код [https://www.mycompiler.io/view/Gg0d3jrzPSH]

Comment: Ну и что нам делать с этими весёлыми картинками? Создайте online fiddle, или хотя бы выложите форматированным текстовым кодом CREATE TABLE таблиц + INSERT INTO с примером данных (5-10 записей на таблицу), а также требуемый ответ для именно этих данных, с подробными пояснениями.

Comment: @Akina извиняюсь , щас выложу код

Comment: @Akina [https://www.mycompiler.io/view/Gg0d3jrzPSH]  вот код с данными

Comment: @Akina   нужно суммировать значение поле `dslamType_id`  который ссылается на поле [dslamtype.id]  и сгруппировать по полю  [sats.sats_id]  который ссылается на поле  [sum.id]

Comment: Ок, исходные данные есть. Теперь давай понимать, что у тебя в требуемом результате. *нужно суммировать значение поле dslamType_id* - там у тебя либо 4, либо 5, откуда может взяться сумма в тысячу? Просил же - с подробными пояснениями. Каждое число требуемого результата - как именно оно получено? PS. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c2a213793bb37c0d41bd79413fb1f42

Comment: @Akina,  таблица под именем `dslam`  , там  где `sats_id = 1`  сумма должна получится - 992.   где `sats_id = 2` сумма должна равняться  - 704

Comment: @Akina т.к   `sats_id = 1 - SATS 6/000`,  `sats_id = 2 - SATS 7/000`.   А `dslamType_id = 5 - 288, dslamType_id = 4 - 128 `,

Comment: @Akina, вы суммировали поле dslamType_id, а нужно суммировать по  `dslamtype.id`   т.к   `JOIN dslam ON dslamType_id = dslamtype.id`

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте текст вопроса. Весь, полностью!!! Что за, право слово, "тут играем, тут не играем, тут рыбку заворачивали..."?

Comment: @Akina,  хорошо. исправил,  теперь возможно более понятен вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получается вот так:

```sql
-- объединение
SELECT `sum`.name AS `категория`,
       COUNT(sats.id) AS `пользователи`,
       sums.`сумма`
FROM sats
JOIN `sum` ON sats.sats_id = `sum`.id
JOIN ( SELECT dslam.sats_id, SUM(dslamtype.name) `сумма`
       FROM dslam
       JOIN dslamtype ON dslam.dslamType_id = dslamtype.id
       GROUP BY dslam.sats_id ) sums ON sums.sats_id = sats.sats_id
GROUP BY `sum`.name, sums.`сумма`
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=131e7feba9ea1820d90629f987d9bd37) с некоторыми пояснениями.

Проверьте логику.

Comment: да. работает. спасибо большое ! пойду разобраться в своих косяках

Comment: @Misterjunior Я не зря прошу проверить именно логику запроса. То, что результат соответствует ожиданию - ещё не гарантия.

Comment: я у себя проверил, работает .  а каким  образом работает  смотрю проверяю на примерах